# Calculate the catenary of transmission lines between two transmission towers with the following parameters.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Parameters we have to work with:

1) Distance between two towers
2) End point height (height of tower 2)
3) Start point height (height of tower 1)
4) Radius of curvature
5) Sag

Is it possible to calculate the equation of a catenary given only these parameter? I am focused on both cases where towers can be equal height AND different height.

I'm trying to implement this in excel and need a bit of guidance.

I am aware that y = a * cosh(x/a) is one of the derived equations pertaining to catenaries.

Comment: Radius of curvature where? What is your definition of “sag?”

Comment: @amd Definition of "sag" https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sag, https://www.quora.com/What-is-sag-in-electrical-engineering, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogging_and_sagging

Comment: @John T https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=catenary+two+points